# Spark cannot find case class on classpath

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, generated-code

I have an issue where Spark is failing to generate code for a `case class`.  Here is the spark error

`Caused by: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 52, Column 43: Identifier expected instead of '.'`

Here is the referenced line in the generated code

`/* 052 */   private com.avro.message.video.public.MetricObservation MapObjects_loopValue34;`

It should be noted that `com.avro.message.video.public.MetricObservation` is a nested `case class` in part of a larger hierarchy.  It is also used in other places in the code fine.  It should also be noted that this pipeline works fine if I use the `RDD` API, but I want to use the `Dataset` API because I want to write out the `Dataset` in parquet.  Has anyone seen this issue before?

I'm using Scala 2.11 and Spark 2.1.0.  I was able to upgrade to Spark 2.2.1 and the issue is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Do you think that [SI-7555](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7555) or something like it has any bearing on this?  I have noticed the past that Scala reflection has had issues generating TypeTags for statically nested classes.  Do you think something like that is going on or is this strictly a catalyst issue in spark?  You might want to file a spark ticket too.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that changing the package name of the affect class "fixes" (ie made go away) the problem.  I really have no idea why this is or even how to reproduce it in a small test case.  What worked for me was I just created a higher level package that work.  Specifically `com.avro.message.video.public` -> `com.avro.message.publicVideo`.